# "Statement(s) could not be prepared" error in SSIS using a UDF

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a data flow task in SSIS '08, with an OLEDB data source. The query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.udf_CreateCCISSentenceDuration(probation_year, probation_month, probation_day)
FROM sentence
```

I pared down the query just to make this more readable. I get the following error regardless:

```
Error at 11012 DATA [Data Records [27]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred.
Error code: 0x80040E14
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E14
Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80040E14
Description: "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggreate
"dbo.udf_CreateCCISSentenceDuration", or the name is ambiguous.".
```

This query works fine in SSMS. If I remove the "dbo." owner part, I get "'udf_CreateCCISSentenceDuration' is not a recognized built-in function name.". The database I am running this against is a SQL 2005 instance. I've done searches, but can't find anything relating to this error and UDFs. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And are you sure that the connection to SQL Server is to the correct database?

Comment: Also, is the account that you used in SSMS the same one, or at least have the same permissions, as the one for SSIS?

Comment: Lamak: Yes, and @billinkc: I just double checked, and yes, both connections are made with the same account with the same permissions.

Comment: Since you've pared the query down, does the column for the scalar UDF have an alias? What's listed is an anonymous column. Something like `) AS myColumn FROM sentence`

Comment: No, it's actually part of a concatenated string. But I get the same error whether all the rest of the query is there or not. I had to move a chunk of the query out into a UDF due to some value manipulation I had to do that involved some conditional math. It all worked fine until I put the UDF in there.

Comment: Where my train of thought is going though is that without an alias to the results of the UDF call, SSIS won't know what to call that column and therefore won't be able to prepare the metadata. Try giving the resulting column a name ` AS MyConcatenatedColumn` and see if that clears it up.

Comment: I think bill's on the right track. SSIS runs all queries with SET FMTONLY ON to figure out metadata (well, they finally fixed it in SQL2012 SP1.) My guess is that it's not getting back good metadata when it does that. See Aaron Bertrand's response in this thread: http://www.developmentnow.com/g/113_2007_7_0_0_999793/Create-function-with-missing-dependency-works-in-SSMS-and-sqlcmd-but-not-using-ADO.htm

Can you SET FMTONLY ON in the database and then run the same query? Sorry, I don't have a 2005 instance handy to test it.

Comment: Spot on. When I add SET FMTONLY ON ahead of the query in SSMS, it blows out with the same error.

My problem with aliasing is that the UDF is in the middle of a concatenation. Something like:

    <columnname> + '|' + <UDF> + '|' + <columnname>

The entire concatenation is aliased at the end, but I cannot alias the UDF in the middle. Suggestions?

Comment: So in the category of "learn something new every day", I discovered that I am able to change the delimiter in a flat file destination to something other than a comma. Not sure how I've missed that after all these years.

So instead of building the pipe-delimited string in the query, I can let the flat file connection take care of the pipes, allowing me to alias each column (and my UDF), and the task works.

Thank you everyone for the help. It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Gary – add your workaround as an answer and earn some upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't really an SSIS issue. To help determine if it is, try reproducing this error outside of SSIS to debug it by writing a stored proc with the same function call. In essence you'll need to store the stored proc on the server/database instance your  oledb connection originates the request from.

If you get a similar error, do a 4 part refernce to the server, db, owner and finally function to see if that works (e.g. [myServerWhereFunctionIs].[myDatabaseInstanceWhereFunctionIs].[ownerSchemaOfFunction].udf_Function

Answer (score -2):

For me query is the problem for that error. After modifying my query it work fine. So please go through your query based on the description in the error message.

Comment: like what? what sort of syntax do we need to use? google search results seems poor